# Django: Trying to set user as a foreign key in migration raises a ValueError

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, valueerror

I have a Member class extending the User model

```
  class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    # extra fields
```

When I try to use the following custom migration to prepopulate the database with an initial data set from a file

```
from django.db import migrations
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import pandas as pd


def add_data_from_file(apps, schema_editor):
    Member = apps.get_model('persons', 'Member')
    df = pd.read_excel('path_to_file', sheet_name='sheet_name')

    for ind in df.index:
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=df.username[ind],
            first_name=df.first_name[ind],
            last_name=df.last_name[ind],
            email=df.email[ind],
            password=df.password[ind],
        )
        Member.objects.create(
            user=user,
            date_start=df.date_start[ind],
            date_stop=df.date_stop[ind]
        )


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('persons', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(add_data_from_file),
    ]
```

Django raises:

> ValueError: Cannot assign "<User: testuser>": "Member.user" must be a "User" instance.

Any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: IMHO this implementation should be done from a managment command, or even loaddata. Doing it in migrations may confuse developers who may work on it later on how the data is being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why the migration itself doesn't work, but loading the data it via management command works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

For use user model in your migration file function, you must get the User with **apps.get_model** function even if you defined custom user model, you aren't allow to get user model with `get_user_model`. like this.

```
User = apps.get_model('account', 'User')
```

when you get user model with this way, you didn't get this error `ValueError: Cannot assign ...`